# replace whole word from expression in python ignore arithmetic operator

Tags: python, str-replace

I have an expression as string like `"(addtwo*decimal*p_cost)/(cost+density)"`.
I want to replace cost only but but its replacing `p_cost` as well like -
`p_"replaced value"`. I have tried word boundaries but no luck please help.

```
expr = '(addtwo*decimal*p_cost)/(cost+density)'

expr = string.replace(expr, r"\b%s\b" % str(' cost '), str(3)) not doing anything.
```

Comment: If you want to do a regular expression substitution, use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex.

```
import re
expr = '(addtwo*decimal*p_cost)/(cost+density)'
print(re.sub(r"\bcost\b", "3", expr))
```

**Output:**

```
(addtwo*decimal*p_cost)/(3+density)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

expr = r'(addtwo*decimal*p_cost)/(cost+density)'

expr2 = re.sub("(?<![_])cost(?![_])","COST", expr)
print(expr2)
```

Insert all characters inhibiting the replacement of search word in the square brackets before (`(?<![_])`) and after (`(?![_])`) of the search word (`cost` in this case) in the regex pattern string.